# Why net beans give false errors on creating qt application

Tags: c++, macos, qt, netbeans

I am working c++ in Netbeans in mac,it was properly working but now when i create a new QtApplication and create a QtForm it gives error

```
unexpected token: :
```

in editor, and the project is running and building properly can any one tell me what is the issue because i am unable to get my class members through object everything is underlined red

Comment: What's the code that causes the error?

Comment: All code are underlined red in the QtFrom header and cpp files